# Generating an NFL schedule in C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

I'm working on a project and I need to generate an NFL schedule. I'm really struggling to get it to come out right. It should come out with 256 games spread across 17 weeks - each team has 16 games.

Each Team object I have has an ArrayList of opponents that the team has to play for the season. This part is working correctly.

So now, I'm at the point where I have an ArrayList of 32 teams and each team has an ArrayList of 16 opponents. I need to create 17 weeks based on these opponents and being mindful of each team's bye week.

Here's the code that I am using:

```
ArrayList weeks = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < Constants.RegularSeasonWeeks; i++)
            {
                Week w = new Week(i + 1);
                for (int j = 0; j < teams.Count; j++)
                {
                    Team team = (Team)teams[j];
                    if (!(team.ByeWeek == w.WeekNumber) &&     !w.DoesTeamPlayThisWeek(team))
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < team.Opponents.Count; k++)
                        {
                            Team awayTeam = (Team)team.Opponents[k];
                            if (!awayTeam.Scheduled)
                            { 
                                if (!(GetOpponentsByeWeek(teams,   awayTeam.TeamID) == w.WeekNumber) && !w.DoesTeamPlayThisWeek(awayTeam))
                                {
                                    Game gm = new Game(awayTeam, team);
                                    w.AddGame(gm);
                                    ((Team)team.Opponents[k]).Scheduled = true; 
                                    for (int l = 0; l < teams.Count; l++)
                                    {
                                        Team t = (Team)teams[l];
                                        if (t.TeamID == awayTeam.TeamID)
                                        {
                                            ArrayList tOpps = ((Team)teams[l]).Opponents;
                                            for (int m = 0; m < tOpps.Count; m++)
                                            {
                                                if (((Team)teams[m]).TeamID == team.TeamID) 
                                                {  
                                                    ((Team)teams[m]).Scheduled = true;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } 
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (team.ByeWeek == w.WeekNumber)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
                weeks.Add(w);
            }
            return weeks;
```

This is coming close, but something is still off.. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT ---

When I run it at this point, I come out with ~248 games. It varies by a game or two every time. No team has more than 16 games, but a couple of teams have 14 or 15.

Comment: you can add more details to what's coming off ? what is the problem that you are stuck ? that way it would be precise point on how someone could help answer you.

Comment: I added a description of the issue that I'm having. Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: You can save a lot of casts by using `List<Team>`s instead of `ArrayList`s. In addition, you seem to have unused code in lines 6-9 (counted from below).

Comment: Yeah, disregard that unused code at the bottom. I just haven't gotten around to that part yet.

Comment: Did you resolve this in the end?

Comment: I never did....